# Unable to load small graph to neo4j

Tags: csv, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am trying to load a graph of .3GB to neo4j using Neo4j Desktop (3.4.0) browser.  I have set heap to 4 GB and page cache to 16 GB. However in between the browser looses connection and I am unable to load the graph. I am using the following command to load the graph:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:\\graphUnioned.csv" AS csvLine 
MERGE (s:Node {value:csvLine.s}) 
MERGE (o:Node {value:csvLine.o}) 
MERGE (s)-[:REL]->(o) 
RETURN *;
```

Is there some way by which I may accelerate the loading of graph

I am running neo4j on windows server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is **not with loading** the graph but with **what you are returning**.

You are returning the **whole graph**, and the browser will try to plot/visualize this, plotting these many objects on the browser may make it unresponsive.

**Assuming the issue is with data load I would suggest following steps:**

1. Add an index on the keys on Node (here 'value'): Run this before running the second query.

> `CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:Node) ASSERT n.value IS UNIQUE`

2. Remove RETURN clause.
3. Use periodic commit.

> ```
> USING PERIODIC COMMIT  
> LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:\\graphUnioned.csv" AS csvLine  
> MERGE (s:Node {value:csvLine.s})
> MERGE (o:Node {value:csvLine.o})  
> MERGE (s)-[:REL]->(o);
> ```

4. **(OPTIONAL)** Use only one merge in each query (Separate the query to one merge per query).

Comment: Is it possible to visualize a small subset of the graph after loading it. If yes, how?

Comment: Try to visualize in the different query after loading, and importantly use limit.

Comment: Are you able to load the data?

Comment: Which query can one use to visualize the graph. Yes now the loading succeded

Comment: Try this :  MATCH (n)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-() 
RETURN n, r LIMIT 25;

Comment: don't set limit to too high

Comment: Sure. I am facing a different issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54435055/unknown-function-algo-getnodebyid. Can you try helping with that too

Comment: Okay, I will check

Comment: I know how to find densely connected component. Do you know how to visualize them: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54453179/visualize-connected-components-in-neo4j

Comment: I don't have an experience of connected components and these algorithms, I tried to answer, Please check.