# Unknown function 'algo.getNodeById'

Tags: neo4j, connected-components

I tried to run the following command in Neo4j however it gives the error Unknown function 'algo.getNodeById'. I am using Neo4j desktop (3.4.0) and I am running this command in Neo4j browser:

```
CALL algo.unionFind.stream('', ':REL', {})
YIELD nodeId,setId

RETURN algo.getNodeById(nodeId).id AS user, setId
```

I want to find connected components (top10 maximum connected) in my graph. Any other solution which can help me visualize the connected component in the graph will also work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the older versions of algorithms don't have `algo.getNodeById()` included. If you can try to use the latest graph algorithms, not sure how this works with Neo4j Desktop, but I would try to reinstall them. You could also upgrade your Desktop version.

If none of this is available remember that `algo.getNodeById()` just matches the node by its internal ID and you can get the same functionality by using the following.

```
CALL algo.unionFind.stream('', ':REL', {})
YIELD nodeId,setId

MATCH (node) where id(node) = nodeId
RETURN node.id AS user, setId
```

Comment: Thanks. Also is it possible to visualize the connected component. If yes, then how

Comment: please ask a separate question

Comment: Asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54453179/visualize-connected-components-in-neo4j